# 15.10 - Suspend job starts by itself - docked laptop - closed lid - ext. display

Tags: 15.10, suspend, power-management, ubuntu-gnome

I have just installed and set up my HP Elitebook 8440p with Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 64bit and Gnome 3.18
During the installation, everything went nice, while the laptop was docked and the lid was closed. I didn't experience any sudden suspend.
Then, after installing the nvidia driver (nVidia NVS 3100m - Driver Version 340.96) and rebooting a couple of times, the laptop would suspend by it self.
This was happening either during X loading (after the splash screen) either after gdm login (or even during) or either during a shutdown/reboot.
Some times it suspends immediately after a wake up.
Sometimes no screen is restored after a wake up (the laptop screen or the external one).

It's a frustrating situation.
My previous Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 LTS install, didn't have this problem.

---

I did search as much as I could to find any solutions or suggestions, so this is what I've tried:

Created the file

`/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.disable-suspend.pkla`

with the following content

```
[Disable suspend (upower)]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.suspend
ResultActive=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultAny=no

[Disable suspend (logind)]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.suspend
ResultActive=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultAny=no

[Disable suspend when others are logged in (logind)]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.suspend-multiple-sessions
ResultActive=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultAny=no
```

So that the systems ability to suspend was disabled
It wasn't effective...

Of course, I have tried many settings of gnome shell as well

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESjuL.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GI2Aa.png

...and also `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power` in dconf-editor

Also, I know that even when my system seems to run normal after successfully login in gnome, if I try to reboot or shutdown, nothing happens!
It turns out that there is a suspend job running...

```
nikos@elitebook:~$ sudo reboot
Failed to start reboot.target: Transaction is destructive.
```

And here is the job

```
nikos@elitebook:~$ systemctl list-jobs 
JOB  UNIT                               TYPE     STATE  
2160 suspend.target                     start    waiting
2161 systemd-suspend.service            start    running
2165 anacron-resume.service             start    waiting
```

I can either `reboot -f` to reboot or cancel the job 
`systemctl cancel 2161`
and reboot normally.

Note that this problem occurs only while the laptop is docked and the lid is closed. On normal use, this problem is nonexistent.

I wouldn't mind disabling or removing system suspend completely from my system. What else can I try to solve this?

**EDIT
(NOT solved though)**

Continuing my search, I found that I can edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`
 It cointained the variable `#HandleLidSwitch` set to `suspend` which I changed. Here is what my file looks like:

```
[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=ignore
#HandleHibernateKey=ignore
#HandleLidSwitch=ignore
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=no
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=yes
```

My problem still persists...

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to fix it

I found a fix in this bug comment

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1450009

It involves editing `/lib/udev/rules.d/70-power-switch.rules`

and adding this line

```
SUBSYSTEM=="input", KERNEL=="event*", ATTRS{name}=="* WMI hotkeys", TAG+="power-switch"
```

Maybe someone will find this helpfull someday ;)

Comment: Thanks, worked for me as well on Ubuntu 18.04